# Fix Jdeveloper ADF Mobile Preview Bug

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i use Windows 8 and JDeveloper 11.1.2.4.0 with Oracle ADF Mobile. The problem i am facing is that when ever i open '**Preview**' of my Application UI, it gives me Error and whole Jdeveloper becomes hanged. The error box shows nothing just title `Unexpected Error`

Searching online, i got to know that it's a bug and many people are facing it.

Does anyone know any way to fix this please ?

Thankyou

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem? I am going through the same problem.

Comment: No, that's a bug from oracle. I installed windows 7 for my project